# C++ Looping / Array

Tags: c++

Can you help me with this im having a hard time with this problem.

Create a program that will accept a positive integer, say n, and outputs all combination of 2 positive integers that sums up to .

Sample output:
Enter a number: 10

10 is defrayed as:

1+9 2+8 3+7 4+6 5+5

Note: Using loop or array

Thank you for the help!!

Comment: You should take two arguments, required total, and number of contributors, bonus points if you allow negative numbers

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code writing service, please show your efforts include any error traces

Answer (score 1):

```
int main(){
    int n;
    cout<<"Enter a number: ";
    cin>>n;
    cout<<n<<" is defrayed as"<<endl;
    for(int i=1;i<=n/2;i++){
        cout<<i<<"+"<<n-i<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(){
int no;
printf("Enter the no ");
scanf("%d",&no);
printf("The sum can be ----\n");
for(int i=1;i<n/2;i++){
    printf("%d + %d\n",i.n-i);
}
cout<<endl;
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Thank you appreciate it much! :)

Answer (score 0):

There is one exception. Number 1 can not be represented as a sum of two positive numbers.:) So for this exception the demonstrative program below outputs `0 + 1 = 1`.

Here you are

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    while ( true )
    {
        std::cout << "Enter a non-negative number (0-exit): ";

        unsigned int n = 0;
        std::cin >> n;

        if ( !n ) break;

        for ( unsigned int i = n == 1 ? 0 : 1, j = n - i; i <= j; i++, j-- )
        {
            std::cout << i << " + " << j << " = " << n << std::endl;
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

If to enter sequentially `1 10 0` then the output will be

```
Enter a non-negative number (0-exit): 1
0 + 1 = 1

Enter a non-negative number (0-exit): 10
1 + 9 = 10
2 + 8 = 10
3 + 7 = 10
4 + 6 = 10
5 + 5 = 10

Enter a non-negative number (0-exit): 0
```

The ternary operator used to initialize the loop variable i

```
unsigned int i = n == 1 ? 0 : 1
```

can be replaced the following way

```
unsigned int i = n != 1
```

that is the loop statement will look like

```
for ( unsigned int i = n != 1, j = n - i; i <= j; i++, j-- )
```

Comment: Thank you! Its a big help :)